# Implementing a kext that intercepts file system usage

Tags: c, macos, kernel, kernel-extension

how do most of antivirus software block file system io in case of an infected file? I suppose all the magic resides in some custom kext to do that. Can anyone point me to some topics on this? Some working example would also be great. I've read apple docs about kext development, but mostly it's all about hardware drivers and i could not find what i need.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it seems that i found what i needed. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2005/tn2127.html

Comment: Link in answer is dead.